# C variable initialization by default

Tags: c

In C, why does the following result in x[1] being 2?

```
int a = 2, x;
...
printf("x[1] = ", &x[1])
```

Comment: Need more context/infomration.  The printf does not have a format specification in the string, so I don't know how you are getting a x[1] being 2 and you are taking the address of an element in an array, not getting the value of x[1].  Can you provide more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't. It results in undefined behaviour where *anything* can happen. You cannot access elements beyond the end of an array in a defined manner.

What's most likely happening is that `a` is just "above" `x` on the stack, which results in `x[1]` having the same address as `a`, but it's by no means guaranteed.

This is, of course, assuming that your `printf` is a typo. As it stands, it doesn't even compile. I'm *assuming* it's a typo since the question title just asks about the value of `x[1]` rather than the output.

To get it to work, you'd have to use something like:

```
printf ("x[1] = %d\n", (&x)[1]);
```

which also prints `2` on my system, but may do something totally different elsewhere.

Comment: In that example it will give the error "subscripted value is neither array nor pointer".Since x is a int.

Comment: @dreamcrash: correct. I've added extra detail to cover what's most likely being asked.